# Join two Oracle queries

Tags: oracle, join

I've to query from two tables and want one result.. how can i join these two queries?

First query is querying from two tables and the second one is only from one.

```
select pt.id,pt.promorow,pt.promocolumn,pt.type,pt.image,pt.style,pt.quota_allowed,ptc.text,pq.quota_left 

from promotables pt,promogroups pg ,promotablecontents ptc ,promoquotas pq where pt.id_promogroup = 1 and ptc.country ='049' and ptc.id_promotable = pt.id and pt.id_promogroup = pg.id and pq.id_promotable = pt.id order by pt.promorow,pt.promocolumn

select  pt.id,pt.promorow,pt.promocolumn,pt.type,pt.image,pt.style,pt.quota_allowed from promotables pt where pt.type='heading'
```

Comment: Do you want to JOIN the queries or CONCATENATE them? These mean different things in SQL. A join usually implies join criteria (`select from a join b on a.col = b.col`) whereas concatenation is just appending the results of one query to the other (e.g. via `UNION` or `UNION ALL`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UNION or UNION ALL. As long as you have the same number of columns and they are compatible types that should do what you want.

```
SELECT pt.id, pt.promorow, pt.promocolumn, pt.type, pt.image, pt.style, pt.quota_allowed, ptc.text, pq.quota_left 
FROM promotables pt, promogroups pg, promotablecontents ptc, promoquotas pq 
WHERE pt.id_promogroup = 1
AND ptc.country ='049' 
AND ptc.id_promotable = pt.id
AND pt.id_promogroup = pg.id
AND pq.id_promotable = pt.id 
UNION
SELECT pt.id, pt.promorow, pt.promocolumn, pt.type, pt.image, pt.style, pt.quota_allowed, NULL, NULL
FROM promotables pt 
WHERE pt.type='heading'
ORDER BY 2, 3
```

If you want to display duplicates (e.g identical rows coming from both queries), use UNION ALL

Comment: Just select NULL for the columns in the other query. This means you will still get the column and results from query 1 may have data there whereas rows from query 2 will always contain NULL for those columns.